# Typescript show incompatible error when type is defined as list of string variants

Tags: typescript

I have a strange TS error in the code below:

```
interface Foo {
  videoType: "A" | "B"
}

interface RS {
  result: Foo[]
}

const fn = (): RS => {
  
  const col = [{
      videoType: 'A',
  }]
  
  return {
    result: col,
  }
}
```

result marks as error with TS Error description:

`TS2322: Type '{ videoType: string; }[]' is not assignable to type 'Foo[]'.   Type '{ videoType: string; }' is not assignable to type 'Foo'.     Types of property 'videoType' are incompatible.       Type 'string' is not assignable to type '"A" | "B"'.`

It is very confused me. Anybody know that is it can be ?

Comment: TypeScript uses heuristics to infer types for literals; these work well in a lot of cases but sometimes it doesn't realize you're going to need a more specific type.  In those situations you should annotate or use a `const` assertion, as shown [here](https://tsplay.dev/W477Km).  Does that meet your needs? If so I'll write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: Thanks you very much @jcalz, It's completely solves my problem !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TypeScript uses various heuristic rules when inferring the type of a variable that is initialized with a [literal value](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Literal).  These heuristic rules work well for a wide range of situations, but they are not perfect.

---

Consider:

```
const arr = [{ message: "hello" }, { message: "goodbye" }];
// const arr: { message: string; }[]
```

Here `arr` is inferred to be an unordered arbitrary-length array of objects with a `message` property of type `string`, and not of a string [literal type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#literal-types) like `"hello"` or `"goodbye"` or a [union](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#union-types) of these.  And that's good, because we wanted to add exclamation points to those messages later:

```
arr.forEach(o => o.message += "!"); // make messages more extreme!
```

People often want to make changes to values in writable locations (like `let` variables or non-[`readonly` properties](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#readonly-properties)), so that's why the heuristics work this way.

---

Now consider:

```
const col = [{ videoType: 'A' }, { videoType: 'B' }];
// const col: { videoType: string; }[]
```

The `col` initializer has *exactly* the same form as the `arr` initializer.  And therefore the compiler infers that the array elements' `videoType` property is of type `string`, not `"A"` or `"B"` or `"A" | "B"`. But it turns out this isn't what you wanted to do with `col`:

```
const fn = (): RS => {

  const col = [{ videoType: 'A' }, { videoType: 'B' }];
  // const col: { videoType: string; }[]

  return {
    result: col, // error! string is not "A" | "B"
  }
}
```

The compiler didn't know that you were going to later take `col` and try to use it as a `Foo[]`.  So you're sad.

---

For use cases like this, you need to tell the compiler in advance what type you want to see, since the heuristic rules don't work for you.  The most straightforward approach is to [annotate](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#type-annotations-on-variables) the variable with the desired type:

```
const fn = (): RS => {
  const col: Foo[] = [{ videoType: 'A' }, { videoType: 'B' }];
  return { result: col }; // okay
}
```

Alternatively, you can take any literal value that you'd like to be interpreted more narrowly (because you don't want to change it), and use a [`const` assertion](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-4.html#const-assertions) to change the inference rules:

```
const fn = (): RS => {
  const col = [{ videoType: 'A' } as const, { videoType: 'B' } as const];
  // const col: ({ readonly videoType: "A"; } | { readonly videoType: "B"; })[]
  return { result: col }; // okay
}
```

Here each element of the array has been `const`-asserted, and so the array element types are inferred to be objects with `readonly` `videoType` properties of literal types.  (I didn't `const`-assert the whole array literal because that would have resulted in a [`readonly` tuple type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#readonly-tuple-types) which is not assignable to a mutable array.)

Here the `const` assertions take more effort than an assertion, but often it's the opposite because the intended type doesn't already exist as a defined interface in your code base and you don't want to write out the whole thing.

---

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?useDefineForClassFields=true&target=9#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgGIHt3IN4ChnIBuwAJhOgCoCeADhAFzIBEAgk8gD7MBCTuAvrlyhIsRCgBKAZRz5kUCAGcArgBswjDOgDaAXQFDcCdCEVhkcKFGQBeZNuzIAtksVwA5g2YALCKtXo7PwANDjOrh5eTO6YJABGVBBBugDcuAD06cjGpuaWUIyOLopunoxmUKDuKcj8erj5AHQw6FAAoojeABRYNgB8yOiNxaUoANR2TACETACUaUI5ZsgwINxwJLbIXbOM0rYDeHJL5saqWw5EpOTUdIwA5Cz3taGOxGSUtF733M-8qXJMtkTMszoUrh9bl4KlUanV9HIFGBlFAQLICAQFCp1IwzqEgdAoK0psgYSB3MhgIpkCB0OZWOwuExeHJBIJFiDzKsAAxbHZ7GT9dHA3LA1SaTB6C5va6fO7IR5-V4Qm5fB6-WoAzEQZGosJYtQaMW1NKCE4rNF2fnIfZCvAEc1naUquXfJ61CzUk7K96q+U-P6ekVmLXIIGO9Di7aOBQbEyqKguqGMBlwzj6iBxkAJpNqnhMOGzera3VomNKQ24yMmgRAA)